# How to get the position of data push in realtime database Anroid Java?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

**I have JSON tree structure like this**

```
SampleData 
 -sampleEmail
   -Push key // Generated by .push() in realtime database
     "data1" : "Sample Data 1"
     "data2" : "Sample Data 2"
     "data3" : "Sample Data 3"
   -Push key // Generated by .push() in realtime database
     "data1" : "Sample Data 1"
     "data2" : "Sample Data 2"
     "data3" : "Sample Data 3"
```

Does firebase have method to get the position of push key like (0, 1, 2,...) Im working with RecyclerViewAdapter and I want to compare the holder position and the position in database to get the specific item. Is there a way to that?

Answer (score 1):

Here, you can see your answer. I comment on that portion of what you need, you can check this code snippet:

```
    FirebaseRecyclerOptions<ModelClass> options =
            new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<QuizSetMode> ()
                    .setQuery ( FirebaseRef (SampleData/SampleEmail), ModelClass.class )
                    .build ();


    FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<ModelClass,ViewHolder> adapter =
            new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<ModelClass, ViewHolder>(options) {
                @Override
                protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final StudentViewHolder2 holder, final int position, @NonNull final ModelClass model) {

                    String listPostKey = getRef(position).getKey();
                    // This is your Desired answer (listPostKey)
                    // Here You can Get all the push key in (listPostKey)
                    // You Can Perform any operation here using listPostKey



                }

                @NonNull
                @Override
                public StudentViewHolder2 onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) {
                    View view  = LayoutInflater.from ( viewGroup.getContext () ).inflate ( R.layout.quiz_topics,viewGroup,false );
                    StudentViewHolder2 viewHolder  = new StudentViewHolder2(  view);
                    return viewHolder;

                }

                @Override
                public void onDataChanged() {
                    super.onDataChanged();

                    recyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    progressDialog.dismiss();


                }


            };
```